# Using the built in zip extraction in Windows 11, extracting to a network share on samba doesn't allow execution of a program

Tags: windows-11, zip

Using the built in zip extraction in Windows 11, extracting to a network share on samba doesn't allow execution of a program, however.
Extracting with Winrar works fine.

I have a zip file with an executable and its various files - not installer - in Downloads, or my network share, doesn't seem to matter.

I use the built in zip extractor and extract it to my z:/folder network share (linux/samba).

I get error "Windows cannot access \name\folder\gamefolder\game.exe
you do not have permission to access \name\folder\gamefolder\game.exe Contact your network administrator to request access."

Same with PeaZip.

A zip file with a single .exe extracted this way works.

Extract it with Winrar, and the portable version will run fine.

I do not see any difference in the file/folder security, owner, or rwx attributes.

The question is a) why the difference, b) is there a way to have Windows zip extractor or PeaZip do it the way WinRar does?

Thanks.

EDIT:
On the linux host itself,

- the extracted-not-running version is -rw-r--r-- but
- the winrar extracted-works and extract-local-copy versions both are -rwx-r--r--.

So the x bit doesn't get set by Windows' built-in or Peazip. Interesting.

Comment: See [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200130/17660) and let me know if it worked. If you have another security software installed besides Windows Defender, try disabling it temporarily.

Comment: BTW, think twice about using WinRAR: https://thehackernews.com/2023/08/winrar-security-flaw-exploited-in-zero.html , https://tuxcare.com/blog/hackers-are-using-a-winrar-vulnerability/ . Try 7-Zip. Also, extract *first*, locally, then move files to share.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that was fixed months ago in version 6.23. Extracting locally with Windows zip extractor works, as you suggest. Thanks.  My question is more about why these methods look the same and act differently.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure I want to set "everything" executable. But, that got me thinking and on the linux host itself, the extracted-not-running is -rw-r--r-- but the winrar extracted-works and extract-local-copy versions both are -rwx-r--r--. So the x bit doesn't get set by Windows' built-in or Peazip. Interesting.

Comment: @MikeP: The other answer in my link suggested `chmod +x file.exe`. I guess winrar is smart enough to do it automatically for exe files.

Answer (score 1):

Winrar seems to be smart enough to set automatically the x bit for
`exe` files on SAMBA shares, which Windows' built-in unzip and Peazip
don't do.

To fix this manually, try the command `chmod +x game.exe`.